# Function that calculates age in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to calculate the age of a person. I'm making a function for it that I can use later as well as this time.

Function should take a ID-Number which are 11 characters in `sweden` format which is `560404-1234`.

And return the age of the person just the years. So far I've thought of making a subtraction with example: `Getdate year 2014 - 19+IDNr datepart yy` to get the sum.

Still stuck though.

Cheers

Comment: Can you please explain the format of Swedish ID numbers, for those of us who are not familiar with them?

Comment: where is DOB of particular person & in which format is it?

Comment: I guess you're able to extract one's birthday from the ID-Number yourself. For the actual calculation of age, see Itzik's article here: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/datetime-calculations-part-5

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that the Swedish id number format is YYMMDD followed by something else.

If so, then the following should work to get the date:

```
select cast('19'+left(idn, 6) as date)
```

Then the age would be:

```
select datediff(year, cast('19'+left(idn, 6) as date), getdate())
```

What do the Swedes do about people born in the last 14 or so years?  What happens to those who are over 100 years old?

Comment: Good question. Actually for our business you've to be atleast over 18 years old to be in our systems, and we've got none persons over 114 years old :)

Comment: The Swedish SSN is built on the format `YYMMDD-NNNX` where the `NNN` is a sequence number and the X is a checksum calculated using mod 10; For persons over 100 years old, the dash is replaced by a plus sign. The algorithm used for the checksum is this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

Comment: I was born on Feb 20th, 1965. How old was I on Feb 19th, and how old on Feb 21st?

Comment: It works to some extent. I've tried it out a bit and it fails with the conversion according to this error message 

`Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Comment: This date conversion works under a variety of circumstances:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/32510.  Are you sure all the strings are in this format?

Answer (score 0):

If "dean" is correct, then you can try following code,

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[udfn_Get_Age_In_Years]
(
    @ID_Number varchar(50)
)
Returns int 
--select dbo.[udfn_Get_Age_In_Years]('560404-1234')
as
begin
    Declare @retVal int = 0
    select @retVal = Datediff(mm,col_dob,GETDATE()) / 12 from myTable 
    where ID_Number = @ID_Number
    Return @retVal
end
```

Comment: Why the quotes, this is my real name :) Unfortunatelly, your calculation is not correct, unless you accept to be the same age throughout the entire year, regardless of your birthday date.

Comment: It might work, it's enough if it only returns the amount of years someone is.

Comment: @dean is correct! I have updated my ans, please verify.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer it's similar to the above ones but this is how I've solved it after a while.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[Function_AGE] 
(
    @IdNr varchar(13)

) 
returns int
as

begin



    Declare @Calc int 

    Set @IdNr = (Select Case when LEN(@IdNr) > 11 
    then cast(left(@IdNr, 8) as date)
    else cast('19'+left(@IdNr,6) as date) end) 


    set @Calc = (select datediff(year,@IdNr,getdate())) 

    Return @Calc
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would calculate age of a person, given their age and current date

```
select case 
            when cast(getdate() as date) = cast(dateadd(year, (datediff(year, '1996-09-09', getdate())), '1996-09-09') as date)
                then dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, 0, getdate()))
            else dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, -1, getdate()))
        end as MemberAge
go
```

Answer (score 0):

To Compare a birthdate to @Date, the DATEDIFF gets you close.  Subtract off of that if the month and day haven't occurred yet in the year.

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm,birthdate) > DATEPART(mm,@Date) 
THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthdate AS DATE), @Date) - 1 

WHEN DATEPART(mm,birthdate) = DATEPART(mm,@Date) 
AND  DATEPART(dd,birthdate) > DATEPART(dd,@Date) 
THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, birthdate AS DATE), @Date) - 1

ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR, CAST(birthdate AS DATE), @Date)
END AS Age
```